# Backbone.JS or Marionette.JS Routing without hash change dependency

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, marionette, hashchange

I want to start using JavaScript frameworks - and thought I would try Backbone or Marionette as it is very modular and flexible (from what I can tell).

The only thing that is bothering me at the moment is that they both seem to depend on Routing through hash changes. This is not something I can use, as I have a strict URL structure.

Is there a simple way to change this? Like the template tags in Underscore.JS - or is it a little more tricky?

One problem I have is that I am **not** using Node.js, this is a traditional server set up on Apache (in case the answers rely on Node).

Every example / tutorial I have seen/read/watched/followed depends on the hash change as they are *single page* web apps. Is this the design of Backbone and Marionette? I can deal with no page refreshes - but need the URL's to change to traditional MVC style ones

Comment: `need the URL's to change to traditional MVC style ones`. Just a heads up, but MVC has nothing to do with the URL. What I'm assuming you're referring to is a "pretty URL" which is commonly implemented with MVC frameworks that use RESTful API's. It's very possible to have long, ugly URL's while using an MVC framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `pushState`. And it will only work in modern browsers

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

[Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) and [Backbone.History](http://backbonejs.org/#History)

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) not aide in supporting older browsers with the pushState set to true? Just a thought. I have **no idea** how it could be integrated though!